# make more than one material "shadeless" at once

Tags: materials

i want to make all these materials shadeless. i am used to select every material and choose shadeless and this is very time consuming
i tried many time and searched but can't find the answer
can anyone help me ???!  :(

[image: changing material properties screensot]

Comment: I don't think it would be possible without using scripting.

Comment: it's a real problem with the program really :(